# Graph Theory Cycle Graph Proof

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, proof-writing

$G$ is a graph with $n \geq 3$ vertices and $\delta(G) \geq n/2$. I have already proven in $(a)$ that for each $k<n$, if G contains a copy of $C_k$, then G contains a copy of $P_k$. And in $(b)$, for each k, if G contains a copy of $P_k$, then G contains either a copy of $P_{k+1}$ or a copy of $C_{k+1}$.

I need to use $(a)$ and $(b)$ to prove that G contains a copy of $C_n$. I think that $\delta(G) \geq n/2$ implies that G contains a copy of $P_1$. I don't know how to use $(a)$ and $(b)$ to prove that it must follow that G contains a copy of $P_2$. I know by repeatedly doing this same step using induction I can prove that G must contain a copies all the way up to $P_n$, but I don't know how to finally conclude there is a copy of $C_n$. Can I have some help please showing me how to do this question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct about what you've done so far:

- For a path of length $1$, you don't even need the full power of $\delta(G) \ge \frac n2$: you just need to know that your graph has at least one edge.
- If we have a path of length $k$, then by (b) we can either extend it to a path of length $k+1$ or complete it to a cycle of length $k+1$. By (a), provided $k+1<n$, the cycle of length $k+1$ gives us a path of length $k+1$, too. So by induction, we can keep extending our path until (a) stops working...

...and now all you have to realize is that the only way (a) can stop working is if we have a cycle of length $n$, which is what we wanted!

Another possibly helpful thought for your intuition: if we end up with a path of length $n-1$, then it looks like (b) gives us two alternatives of either a path of length $n$ or a cycle of length $n$. However, there is no such thing as a path of length $n$ in our graph: it only has $n$ vertices, so $n-1$ is the longest path possible. So if we reach a length-$(n-1)$ path, then (b) will give us a length-$n$ cycle, at which point we are done!

---

*(I am deliberately avoiding using the notation $P_k$, $C_k$, because graph theorists can't agree on whether $P_k$ has $k$ vertices or $k$ edges, and the difference is actually rather important in this proof.)*

Comment: Can you show me please how to use induction to keep extending the path as I am confused on this part please ? I understand now how to conclude a cycle of length $n$ is formed.

Comment: I thought this was something you had already figured out how to do from your question. Since it is not, can you rephrase "I know by repeatedly doing this same step using induction I can prove that G must contain a copies all the way up to $P_n$" so that I know what you understand and what you're confused by?

Comment: I don’t know how to do a proof by induction to prove G contains copies all the way up to $P_n$. By this I mean I am struggling with the inductive step notably.

Comment: I give a short explanation of that in the second bullet point of my answer; is there a difficulty with that?

Comment: so your two bullet points are the induction argument to confirm ? Thanks.

Comment: So does your two bullet points suffice for a proof of my question ? If so I can accept your answer with a tick.

Comment: They are intended to, but only you can answer if they suffice :)

Comment: It made sense to me and answered my question as I had already started the proof so I'll accept it. Thanks for your help : )